# Load testing got stuck while running script in Non-GUI

Tags: testing, jmeter, performance-testing

I executed a load test of 3000 users with ramp up time of 120 secs and constant timer of 5 sec. And while  execution is gonna be completed the execution got stuck.
summary +     11 in 00:00:31 =    0.4/s Avg:   503 Min:   299 Max:  1447 Err:     0 (0.00%) Active: 136 Started: 3000 Finished: 2864
summary =  82078 in 00:07:42 =  177.7/s Avg:  2639 Min:   233 Max: 244776 Err:   177 (0.22%)
It got stuck in the above lines and i am waiting for more than a hour and its in the same state.

Can anyone please help me on this.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Take a [thread dump](https://www.baeldung.com/java-thread-dump) to see what exactly JMeter threads are doing, this is the only way to see where JMeter (and in fact any other Java program) is "stuck"

---

Other things to check are:

1. Make sure to define reasonable timeouts, i.e. for [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) samplers you can set them using [HTTP Request Defaults](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/why-its-so-important-use-jmeters-http-request-defaults) configuration element:

   [image]

   in the majority of cases default value is "no timeout" so JMeter can wait forever if the server is not responding
2. Make sure to follow [JMeter Best Practices](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html)
3. Ensure that JMeter has enough headroom to operate in terms of CPU, RAM, not spending all the time doing garbage collection, etc. If you don't have any better monitoring toolchain you can use [JMeter PerfMon Plugin](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PerfMon/) for this purposes
4. If you cannot conduct the required load from one machine due to lack of resources - consider switching to [Distributed Testing](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html)